# How is the color of a disabled label determined based on the background color?

Tags: .net, winforms, custom-controls

I have a custom-drawn control and I'd like its color to match the color of the standard `Label` control. However, I haven't been able to determine the color of a **disabled** label. The screenshot below shows the labels with three different backgrounds. Is it possible to get the color with which the *Disabled* label is drawn, so that I can use it in my custom drawing?

[image: Labels on different backgrounds]

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mean you want to get the disabled color of label which comes with winforms? If so, why you have added this image? What that adds to this post?

Comment: I added it to illustrate that the color is actually dynamically determined by Winforms based on the background and it is not a property of the `Label` control itself. I would like to replicate this behavior in my custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Label.OnPaint` by using Reflector:

```
if (base.Enabled)
{
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, r, nearestColor, flags);
}
else
{
    Color foreColor = TextRenderer.DisabledTextColor(this.BackColor);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, r, foreColor, flags);
}
```

Where `TextRenderer.DisabledTextColor`:

```
internal static Color DisabledTextColor(Color backColor)
{
    Color disabledTextColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
    if (ControlPaint.IsDarker(backColor, SystemColors.Control))
    {
        disabledTextColor = ControlPaint.Dark(backColor);
    }
    return disabledTextColor;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a single built-in method or property I could use to get the "disabled" color, but in the end I replicated the code from `Label.OnPaint` in my control and it works correctly. Thanks!